# TestStack White - Open app in WPF framework

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, white-framework

I want to do some automation tasks on a WPF application using Test stack white and Visual studio 2017

If I manually open the app in windows explorer and then use the tool "Inspect" or "Visual UI Automation" to get the element, the element is 'regconized' and the frameworkid is **WPF**.

However, if I open the app within Visual Studio using Application.Launch("path to app") or Process.Start("path to app"), then the opened app will have frameworkid = **Win32**

-> This makes all the script after that will not work. This is because I used automationID, but if the application is open as "win32", there is no identification.

May I know how to solve this problem? I tried to search for the solution but seems like no one asked before.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the app using Process.Start("path") and then navigate through all windows available get the window you desire by the title